# Jenkins upgrade to 2.58 can't launch slaves

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I have upgraded Jenkins from 2.55 to 2.58 and the upgrade appears to have taken all our slaves offline.

Jenkins and slaves all running on linux (RHEL 6)

I've read quite a bit about similar issues but nothing that is 100% the same.

Has anyone run into this before?  I've been doing some reading on MACs in sshd_config but haven't had any success getting the slaves restarted.

Any ideas for solution greatly appreciated as I'm probably going to have to shout cake unless I get it sorted by the morning :D

Cheers,
Deon.

Slave log follows -

> [05/03/17 19:55:25] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to . Key
>   exchange was not finished, connection is closed. java.io.IOException:
>   There was a problem while connecting to   at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:834)  at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:703)  at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:617)  at
>   hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:1265)
>     at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:790)
>     at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:785)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Key exchange was not finished, connection is
>   closed.   at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.getOrWaitForConnectionInfo(KexManager.java:95)
>     at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.getConnectionInfo(TransportManager.java:237)
>     at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:786)     ... 9
>   more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot read full block, EOF
>   reached.  at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherInputStream.getBlock(CipherInputStream.java:81)
>     at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:108)
>     at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportConnection.receiveMessage(TransportConnection.java:232)
>     at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:706)
>     at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:502)
>     ... 1 more [05/03/17 19:55:25] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
>   [05/03/17 19:55:25] [SSH] Connection closed.

Comment: I think you are affected by https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43979 . Maybe the MACs workaround helps you.

Comment: Could get it working on one of our debian 7 slaves by commenting out the ecdsa_key and adding "MACs hmac-sha1" to /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: Hi @tweber, thanks for the link.  I ended up reading a bunch of other stuff related to trilead and totally missed that issue.  I didn't have any luck with the suggested fix so I've rolled back Jenkins and we'll be all happy until 2.59 comes out :D